# using stdClass() to create soap request wsdl complex type

Tags: php, soap

After finding PHP soap does not handle arrays with a complex type, I'm now using stdClass()  I've coded something but it creates the soap request in the wrong sequence.  I want the idtag and idtaginfo to be in pairs like below.

```
     <soap:Body>
     <ns:sendLocalListRequest>
     <ns:updateType>full</ns:updateType>
     <ns:listVersion>1</ns:listVersion>

     <ns:localAuthorisationList>

           <ns:idTag>1</ns:idTag>
                   <ns:idTagInfo>
                      <ns:status>good</ns:status>
                    </ns:idTagInfo>

            <ns:idTag>2</ns:idTag>
                   <ns:idTagInfo>
           <ns:status>bad</ns:status>
                    </ns:idTagInfo>

     </ns:localAuthorisationList>

  </ns:sendLocalListRequest>
   </soap:Body>
```

my soap request which is wrong is coming out like the below

```
  <env:Body><ns1:sendLocalListRequest><ns1:updateType>FULL</ns1:updateType>
  <ns1:listVersion>1</ns1:listVersion>

  <ns1:localAuthorisationList>
  <ns1:idTag>1</ns1:idTag><ns1:idTag>2</ns1:idTag>

 <ns1:idTagInfo><ns1:status>good</ns1:status><ns1:status>bad</ns1:status>
  </ns1:idTagInfo>
   </ns1:localAuthorisationList></ns1:sendLocalListRequest></env:Body>
```

this is relevant part of the wsdl

```
 <s:complexType name="SendLocalListRequest">
    <s:annotation>
      <s:documentation>Defines the SendLocalList.req PDU</s:documentation>
    </s:annotation>
    <s:sequence>
      <s:element name="updateType" type="tns:UpdateType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
      <s:element name="listVersion" type="s:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
      <s:element name="localAuthorisationList" type="tns:AuthorisationData"
       minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <s:element name="hash" type="s:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
    </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>

    <s:complexType name="AuthorisationData">
          <s:sequence>
       <s:element name="idTag" type="tns:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <s:element name="idTagInfo" type="tns:IdTagInfo" minOccurs="1"
     maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </s:sequence>
                 </s:complexType>

  <s:simpleType name="UpdateType">
    <s:restriction base="s:string">
      <s:enumeration value="Differential"/>
      <s:enumeration value="Full"/>
    </s:restriction>
  </s:simpleType>

 <s:complexType name="SendLocalListResponse">
    <s:annotation>
      <s:documentation>Defines the SendLocalList.conf PDU</s:documentation>
    </s:annotation>
    <s:sequence>
      <s:element name="status" type="tns:UpdateStatus" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
      <s:element name="hash" type="s:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
    </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>

 <s:complexType name="IdTagInfo">
    <s:sequence>
      <s:element name="status" type="s:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      <s:element name="expiryDate" type="s:dateTime" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <s:element name="parentIdTag" type="tns:IdToken" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </s:sequence>
  </s:complexType>
```

This my code

```
$search_query = new StdClass();
$search_query->updateType = $updatetype;
$search_query->listVersion = $listversion;

 $search_query->localAuthorisationList = new StdClass();

 while ($row = $db->getResult()) {


 $search_query->localAuthorisationList->idTag[] = $row['rfid'];

 $search_query->localAuthorisationList->idTagInfo->status[] = $row['status'];

 }


   ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0"); 

$path        = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
$endpoint    = $wsdl;
$soapOptions = array(    'exceptions'     => 0
                        ,'soap_version'   => SOAP_1_2
                        ,'trace'          => true
                                                                    ,'uri' => $theversion
                        ,'location' => $url
                                                    ); 

$header = new SoapHeader($theversion,'', $ppid);

$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);  

    $response = $client->SendLocalList($search_query);
```

### Update

I've got close but still falling at the last hurdle the following will produce the list

```
while ($row2 = $db->getResult()) { 
$search_query[] = new  SoapStructAuthorisationData($row2['rfid'],array(new 
SoapStructIdTagInfo('ConcurrentTx'))); 
}

// implode with commas and remove last comma

$search_list=implode(', ', $search_query);

$search_list_nocommaend = rtrim($search_list, ', ');
```

a var_dump of this produces SoapStructAuthorisationData, SoapStructAuthorisationData, SoapStructAuthorisationData, SoapStructAuthorisationData, SoapStructAuthorisationData

if I enclose the code above in speech marks like "new  SoapStructAuthorisationData($row2['rfid'],array(new 
    SoapStructIdTagInfo('ConcurrentTx')))";  is will produce the whole thing but this wont show when I do the following

```
  if($soapServiceSend->SendLocalList(new SoapStructSendLocalListRequest($updateType,
     $listversion, 
  array( $search_list_nocommaend ))))
```

if I do something like this for a test piece it works

```
$search=new SoapStructAuthorisationData('BUKIEE',array(new 
SoapStructIdTagInfo('ConcurrentTx')));
```

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I've faced a lot of times this type of problems and I've found the easiest solution: http://www.wsdltophp.com/

Here you upload your WSDL and it will create all the classes needed to communicate with the server.

Try it, and you maybe will find that you don't have to be dealing with the creation of the classes by yourself.

*Ps. I've found that sometimes the data must not be sent as array, so in the general options unmark "**Send An Array As Parameter**"*

**EDIT - Code from Wsdl2PHP**

```
<?php
$soap = new Saop2StructSendLocalListRequest(); 
$soap->SendLocalList(
    new Saop2StructSendLocalListRequest(
        $updateType, 
        $listversion, 
        array (
            new Saop2StructAuthorisationData(), 
            new Saop2StructAuthorisationData(), 
            new Saop2StructAuthorisationData()
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: tried it out, thanks for the tip.  However it doesn't identify the complex type for me.

Comment: In the classes it created, you have Saop2StructSendLocalListRequest, Saop2ServiceSend and Saop2StructSendLocalListRequest. You have to do this: `$soap = new Saop2StructSendLocalListRequest(); $soap->SendLocalList(new Saop2StructSendLocalListRequest($updateType, $listversion, array (new Saop2StructAuthorisationData(), new Saop2StructAuthorisationData(), new Saop2StructAuthorisationData())));`

Comment: Hi thanks Abraham that's got me very close, but spent most the day trying to place multiple records in but as it requires requesting class can't think of a way of taking database results and putting them in if($soapServiceSend->SendLocalList(new SoapStructSendLocalListRequest($updateType,
         $listversion, 
      array(new SoapStructAuthorisationData('a1',array(new SoapStructIdTagInfo('ConcurrentTx'))))
  )
)
  )

Comment: I need to create multiple instances of - new SoapStructAuthorisationData('a1',array(new SoapStructIdTagInfo('ConcurrentTx'))) and put them into the array with a "," comma separating them, I've been trying to create and array in a loop I had similar question posted which might help give you an idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14851933/php-soap-client-how-to-send-multi-dimentional-array-complex-type

Comment: I've got close but still falling at the last hurdle the following will produce the list while ($row2 = $db->getResult()) { $search_query[] = new SoapStructAuthorisationData($row2['rfid'],array(new SoapStructIdTagInfo('ConcurrentTx')));

Comment: Don't use the website, it doesn't work. Download the wsdl2php pear package instead.